# How to define and call external function in main program if it contains int and char as arguments?

Tags: c, function, header-files

So, I have main.c file where my code is, and an external calc.c file where I want to do some calculations. I define a header file in main.c (calc.h) and should simply call the function calc.c at some point. In main.c, I have 3 inputs through the terminal, let's call them a, b and c, and those are some numbers. Depending on the numbers I give as an input, I create a name of the file (e.g. a5b3c7) that I save in "char filename". Then in main.c I do some calculations and write a table of values in this "a5b3c7" file. So it is an array of values. 
Now, after writing down all the values in the table and closing the file "a5b3c7", I want to call calc.c function and do some calculation with the numbers that are in the created table. I need to pass as arguments one int and the name of the file that it should use.

Issues: 
My calc.c function should have 2 inputs, one "int" and other "char".
In header file, calc.h I have:

```
    int calc(int i, char filename);
```

Should I just start the calc.c function as

```
    int calc(int i, char filename){
       FILE * pointer;
       int ...;
       double ...;
       pointer = fopen(filename, "r");
       .
       .
       .
    }
```

? Are the types of functions and argument well defined?
How can I call this function now from the main program?
Should I just write something like

```
    int main (void) {
    ...      
    calc(i, filename);
    ...
    }
```

In tries to get it work I got different errors like "expected ‘char’ but argument is of type ‘char *', "passing argument 1 of ‘fopen’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]", "expected ‘const char * **restrict**’ but argument is of type ‘char’"...

Thanks for help, I am still learning ;)

Comment: You have everything correct (even if perhaps it could be "better" written), apart from one error: in C, strings are `char*`, not `char`. Of course the implications of this cannot fit into these few words, but you can easily look up "strings in C" material.

Answer (score 3):

Use `char *filename` instead of `char filename`. like

```
int calc(int i, char *filename);
```

Comment: Ok seems that at least I get rid of errors. But then I have an additional question... if there are printf statements in the calc.c file and I call it from the main.c should it write the output of printf in a terminal or I need to make a file where my new values from calc.c will be stored?

Comment: @makeasmile it print on terminal.

Comment: Oh ok, I toughts so but it doesn't so it seems I still have some work to do :P Tnx!